# When you have a sentence containing a list separated by commas, do you need to repeat the verb before a preposition?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, lists, conjunction-reduction

I.E.

Which of these is correct?

A. You are cool, funny, and among the most popular of students at this school.

B. You are cool, funny, and are among the most popular of students at this school.

If neither is correct, how would I say what I am trying to say?

Comment: None are technically correct.  Why do you think one of them must be? Ignoring the commas, there are two "mistakes" in your examples.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I can't stand it! Tell me! What are the mistakes?

Comment: @Mitch  "Mistakes" because they're not exactly ungrammatical but... " You are cool, funny, and among the most popular (of) students **in** this school."

Comment: @Mari-LouA, that's only one and I don't see it as a mistake. 'at' or 'in' is fine. What's the other mistake?

Comment: @Mitch I would omit "of": e.g *Among the most popular cuisines in the world is Chinese.* Would you say: *of cuisines*? I personally wouldn't. To be frank it gets wearisome seeing questions on two or three sentences asking which sentence is correct when more often than not, all three are ungrammatical. With hindsight, perhaps I was a little too harsh on the OP.

Comment: There's ungrammatical and there's informal. I don't find any of these ungrammatical (speaker of AmE); people speak and write them all the time without noticing. They may not be standard or newspaper-proper; I think they're fine, but I'm not a newspaper editor.

Comment: @Mitch I agree about the points Mari-Lou mentioned (both are perfectly grammatical and to me no less informal than her suggested versions), but repeating the verb is at least borderline ungrammatical to me. If you repeat the verb, you'll have to repeat (an anaphor of) the subject as well, making it a separate clause (and adding in an extra _and_ in the now reduced list): “You are cool and funny, and you are among the most popular students at this school”.

Comment: That last one is exactly the way to do it. This is the only way that maintains parallelism. The single-word modifiers "cool" and "funny" go together as a list; "among the most..." is not a natural extension of that list.  But this is only modestly odd. Often one sees such constructions as "he is cool, smart, and makes lots of money"

Answer (score 1):

A is fine.  B is not, since it does not satisfy the pattern of conjunction reduction.  To get B, with 3 things coordinated, we'd have to start with:

*"You are cool, you are funny, and you are are among the most popular of students at this school."

so that each conjunct starts in the same syntactic environment, that is: [you are ___].

Answer (score 0):

**A** is better. There is no need to repeat the verb with "are among" as it is already implied.

You are cool, [are] funny and [are] among the most popular of students at this school.

One thing though - remove the comma after "funny" - that shouldn't be there:

```
You are cool, funny and among the most popular of students at this school.
```

Comment: The "Oxford comma" after "funny" is correct, as is omitting it.  Both are acceptable ways of writing a list.